# Mysql tree table join and count Rows

Tags: mysql

I have these three tables below. I want to join them using a MySQL query. Below the tables I've provided also how my output should look like.

`GameTable`:

```
GameID  GameName    
1       NvsA
2       NvsB
3       DvsA
4       NvsE
```

`PlayerOnGame`:

```
GameID  PlayerName  PlayerNumber  PlayerID
1       Clement     7             10
1       Niyoyita    8             11
2       Clement     8             10
2       David       6             5
```

`PlayerdataTable`:

```
GameID  Action  PlayerNumber
1       kick    7
1       pass    8
1       Run     7
1       Kick    7
2       Kick    8
2       Pass    6
2       Run     8
2       Run     8
```

Output for only `PlayerName = Clement`:

```
GameName  Action  ActionCount
NvsA      Kick    2
NvsA      Run     1
NvsB      Kick    1
NvsB      Run     2
```

Please can someone help me with the query to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to count

```
SELECT
    gt.GameName,
    pdt.Action,
    count(pdt.Action) AS ActionCount
FROM GameTable AS gt
INNER JOIN PlayerdataTable AS pdt ON pdt.GameID = gt.GameID
INNER JOIN PlayerOnGame AS pg ON pg.GameID = pdt.GameID AND pg.PlayerNumber = pdt.PlayerNumber
WHERE pg.PlayerName = 'Clement'
GROUP BY gt.GameID , pdt.Action
```

Comment: Thanks raheel am going to try it but the problem here is: i want to count for only PlayerName Clement.